# Is it possible to add items to an arrayList each time a constructor is called?

Tags: java, variables, arraylist, constructor

I have a form in a JSP page. 
A constructor is called from the JSP page.

```
MainProgram main = new MainProgram(input);
```

I want to add the user input with `getParameter()` and pass this to the constructor,
convert it to an int and add it to an `ArrayList`.

```
private static int number;

private ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();

public MainProgram (String input) {    

    try {         
        arr.add(number = Integer.parseInt(input));              
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
}
```

The problem is that each time only the current number is being added, the array is never populated with each new user input submission

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible, but in your code every time a new instance is created, a new `ArrayList` is created for it. You must change this:

```
private ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
```

to an `static` variable:

```
private static ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because a new instance of class MainProgram is created each time and therefore a new ArrayList (arr). If you make arr static then there will be one instance off arr across any MainProgram instances you create. However this won't work across JVM instantiations or certain classloader operations that web containers sometimes do. If you really want to be sure to capture all input I'd write them to disk somehow.